# Manipular views dentro de uma rota abstrata no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routes

Estou criando uma aplicação que utiliza como backend o **Code Igniter** e para o frontend pretendo utilizar o **AngularJS**. O meu problema é que não estou conseguindo entender de qual forma eu irei inserir novos módulos (blocos de código) onde cada módulo deste deve conter seu próprio controler. Em tese, eu entendo que minha página servirá como uma rota `abstract` total, e que para esta rota eu terei diversas `views` que serão meus módulos.

Minha dúvida, basicamente se baseia em como vou fazer para manipular as views já pré-definidas dentro de uma view `abstract`, exemplo:

```
//página inicial -> página abstrata
paginaInicial = {
    views : [ navbar, leftMenu,content,footer]
}
```

Com base nesse contexto, em diversos casos eu provavelmente vou ter que alterar as informações da view `content`e até onde eu entendo, eu só consigo fazer isso se eu for para uma nova rota.

Alguém ai sabe como posso manipular as views que estão presentes dentro de uma rota abstrata? Incluindo, removendo...